# Finding the maximum value of a mulitvariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I was given the following question:

> The **Hardy-Weinberg Law** of genetics describes the relationship between the proportions of different genes in populations. Suppose that a certain gene has three types (e.g., blood
>   types of A, B and O). If the three types have proportions p, q
>   and r, respectively, in the population, then the Hardy-Weinberg
>   law states that the proportion of people who carry two different
>   types of genes equals $f (p, q,r) = 2pq + 2pr + 2qr$. Explain
>   why $p + q + r = 1$ and then show that the maximum value of
>   $f (p, q,r)$ is $\frac23$.

For the first part of the question, I said that p,q, and r each represent a percentage and so in total they must equal one. Is this reasoning correct?

I then set the equation like this: $r=1-p-q$ because this makes it look more like the functions I am used to dealing with. The only problem is that when I take partial derivatives to find the maximum, I end up with zero. I know the answer must be $\frac23$. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are maximizing $f$ subject to a constraint, which is the usual setting for Lagrange multipliers, have you tried that?

Comment: @TokenToucan I have not yet learned Lagrange multipliers - I believe that is the next subchapter. Do I need them to solve?

Answer (score 2):

**Without Lagrange Multipliers.**

Observe first that,
$$f(p,q,r) = 2(pq+pr+qr) = (p+q+r)^2 -(p^2+q^2+r^2) = 1-(p^2+q^2+r^2).$$
To maximize $f$ you want to minimize $p^2+q^2+r^2$ subject to the constraint $p+q+r=1.$ In other words you want to minimize $g(p,q) = p^2+q^2+(1-p-q)^2.$ Then 
$$g_p = 2p -2(1-p-q)= 4p-2+2q=0, \quad g_q = 4q-2+2p =0$$
which implies $p=q=1/3.$ Thus $r= 1/3.$ This implies that $f(p,q,r) = 2/3$ at the minimum value.

Note: $g_p = \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}.$

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand - just a few questions :)

Comment: Why is f(p,q,r) maximized at the minimum value?

Comment: Was my logic for why p+q+r=1 correct?

Comment: Also, where does $f(p,q) = p^2+q^2+(1-p-q)^2$ come from?

Comment: Sorry for using the same function name. The new function that we want to minimize is $g(p,q).$ We get rid of $r$ by using the constraint $p+q+r=1.$